# How to leave out certain rows in input data when creating a line chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I created a line chart in Excel and manipulated the chart data that is attached to it; however, I have some rows of my chart data that I do not want displayed on the line chart. How can I make these rows "invisible" to the line chart so there aren't extra plot lines on the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try un-selecting the column value of the row and checked your results. Hopefully, there will be a column for every row value. By un-selecting respective column would help you to achieve this. Try the below steps:

Right click on the Chart > Select Data > on the "Select Data Source", you have option to edit the value by "Row/Column" > now, un-select the respective row's column to make the row invisible. In the below example, i am trying to make the 2nd row as invisible. So, from the 1st screenshot i have un-selected the 2nd row value (4) and in the 2nd screenshot, you will be able to see that the value made as invisible. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013? The OP is using 2010, so the dialog boxes and options are going to be different.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your helpful answer, I truly appreciate it. I am new to charts and spent so much time trying to figure this out on my own. You saved me more time wasted. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @Dave Thank you. I clicked the arrow and it turned green. Is that all I need to do?

Comment: @Gayle, thank you so much for doing this. Not only does it reward the answerer, it also helps others find the selected answer (Which is often (not always) the best answer). +1